# How to convert string to telebot.types.message in Python?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am learning how to create telegram bots using telebot. The user enters a query strictly of 2 words: "Weather Moscow" or "Humidity Paris". I split the string into 2 list items. Then I want to use 1st element of the list - the city. But this is a string, and telebot can only work with types.message
code 1st, sorry for the russian:

```
sps = message.text.lower().split(' ')
        if len(sps) > 2:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Неверный запрос. Следует вводить так: Погода Москва или Влажность Пермь\n'
                                              'или воспользуйтесь клавиатурой')
        elif sps[0] in ['погода', 'осадки', 'влажность', 'давление', 'ад', 'ветер', 'температура']:
            if sps[0] == 'погода':
                bot.register_next_step_handler(sps[1], send_message_6)
            if sps[0] == 'температура':
                bot.register_next_step_handler(sps[1], send_message_1)
            if sps[0] == 'осадки':
                bot.register_next_step_handler(sps[1], send_message_2)
            if sps[0] == 'ветер':
                bot.register_next_step_handler(sps[1], send_message_3)
            if sps[0] == 'влажность':
                bot.register_next_step_handler(sps[1], send_message_4)
            if sps[0] == 'давление' or 'ад':
                bot.register_next_step_handler(sps[1], send_message_5)
```

code 2nd:

```
def send_message_6(message_6):
    try:
        city = cities_dict.rus_cities[message_6.text.lower()]
        req = requests.get('https://yandex.ru/pogoda/' + str(city))
        html = bs(req.content, 'html.parser')
        current_temp = html.select('.content__row .temp__value')[1].text
        feel_temp = html.select('.term__value .temp__value')[1].text
        wind = html.select('.fact__props .term__value')[0].text
        humidity = html.select('.fact__props .term__value')[1].text
        pressure = html.select('.fact__props .term__value')[2].text
        state = html.select('.link__feelings .link__condition')[0].text
        bot.send_message(message_6.chat.id, f'Итак, вот какая погода в твоем городе\n'
                                          f'Город:{message_6.text}\n'
                                      f'Текушая температура:{current_temp}\n'
                                      f'Ощущается как:{feel_temp}\n'
                                      f'{state}\n'
                                      f'Ветер:{wind}\n'
                                      f'Влажность:{humidity}\n'
                                      f'Давление:{pressure}')

        bot.send_message(message_6.chat.id, 'Назови цифру, которая соответствует твоему запросу:\n'
                                      '1 - Узнать температуру\n'
                                      '2 - Узнать наличие осадков\n'
                                      '3 - Узнать скорость и направление ветра\n'
                                      '4 - Узнать влажность воздуха\n'
                                      '5 - Узнать атмосферное давление\n'
                                      '6 - Узнать все сразу', reply_markup=keyboard3)
    except (AttributeError, KeyError) :
        bot.send_message(message_6.chat.id, 'Видимо, твоего города я не знаю, но я еще учусь')
        pass

def send_message_1(message_1):
    try:
        city = cities_dict.rus_cities[message_1.text.lower()]
        req = requests.get('https://yandex.ru/pogoda/' + str(city))
        html = bs(req.content, 'html.parser')
        current_temp = html.select('.content__row .temp__value')[1].text
        feel_temp = html.select('.term__value .temp__value')[1].text
        bot.send_message(message_1.chat.id, f'Итак, вот что с температурой в твоем городе\n'
                                        f'Город:{message_1.text}\n'
                                        f'Текушая температура:{current_temp}\n'
                                        f'Ощущается как:{feel_temp}\n')
        bot.send_message(message_1.chat.id, 'Назови цифру, которая соответствует твоему запросу:\n'
                                        '1 - Узнать температуру\n'
                                        '2 - Узнать наличие осадков\n'
                                        '3 - Узнать скорость и направление ветра\n'
                                        '4 - Узнать влажность воздуха\n'
                                        '5 - Узнать атмосферное давление\n'
                                        '6 - Узнать все сразу', reply_markup=keyboard3)
    except (AttributeError, KeyError):
        bot.send_message(message_1.chat.id, 'Видимо, твоего города я не знаю, но я еще учусь')
        pass
```

other `def send_message_#` are the same

Comment: please post code instead of screenshots...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please post the code (including the lines where `sps` is created).

In general, `register_next_step_handler()` requires two parameters: The message to follow and a function that is used for the next step (please see [here](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py) for examples).

Try modifying your code the following way (hope the idea will be clear):

```
sps = message.text.lower().split(' ')
        if len(sps) > 2:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Неверный запрос. Следует вводить так: Погода Москва или Влажность Пермь\n'
                                              'или воспользуйтесь клавиатурой')

bot.register_next_step_handler(message, step2)

def step2(message):
    sps = message.text.lower().split(' ')
    if sps[0] == 'погода':
         try:
             city = cities_dict.rus_cities[sps[1]]
             req = requests.get('https://yandex.ru/pogoda/' + str(city))
             html = bs(req.content, 'html.parser')
             current_temp = html.select('.content__row .temp__value')[1].text
             feel_temp = html.select('.term__value .temp__value')[1].text
             wind = html.select('.fact__props .term__value')[0].text
             humidity = html.select('.fact__props .term__value')[1].text
             pressure = html.select('.fact__props .term__value')[2].text
             state = html.select('.link__feelings .link__condition')[0].text

             bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Итак, вот какая погода в твоем городе\n'
                                          f'Город:{message_6.text}\n'
                                      f'Текушая температура:{current_temp}\n'
                                      f'Ощущается как:{feel_temp}\n'
                                      f'{state}\n'
                                      f'Ветер:{wind}\n'
                                      f'Влажность:{humidity}\n'
                                      f'Давление:{pressure}')

    elif sps[1] == 'влажность':
        ...
```

You can create a message via:

```
msg = types.Message(message_id=0,
                    from_user=0,
                    date='',
                    chat = 0,
                    content_type='text',
                    options=[],
                    json_string='')
msg.text = 'Hi there. I am the message text.'
```

But frankly, it seems a bit weird to use :)

Comment: @АлександрКоротких Пасиб!
Have updated the response - please tell me if it is understandable.

Comment: i understand what you mean. the bottom line is that my request can be sent either by pressing the keyboard button. I press "6" - to display the weather, then enter the city, but I want to add the opportunity - doing request of 2 words. I don’t want to create very cumbersome code, so I ask if it is possible to use both types.message for the keyboard and string for 2-word input

Comment: @АлександрКоротких I think you can create a message with `msg = types.Message(text='enter your text here')` or just  `msg = types.Message('enter your text here')`

Comment: i cant get it ` if sps[0] == 'погода':
                bot.register_next_step_handler(telebot.types.Message(text=sps[1]), send_message_6)` and error **TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'text'
**

Comment: Ok, I was mistaken in my previous comment.
I have added a working message creation example in my response

Comment: Извини, я видимо глупый) Пишет, что у телебота нет атрибута types.Вот строка message_6 = bot.types.Message(message_id=0, from_user=0, date='', chat = 0, content_type='text', options=[], json_string='')
                message_6.text = sps[1]

Comment: @АлександрКоротких you need to add `from telebot import types` in your imports section and then just use `message_6 = types.Message(message_id=0, from_user=0, date='', chat = 0, content_type='text', options=[], json_string='')`, without the `bot.` part